# Not able to implement Okta in Angular7

Tags: angular7, okta-api

I am trying to implement Okta in my Angular7 in my application. I am getting the error when I do ng serve.
**"@okta/okta-angular": "^3.2.2"
"@okta/okta-auth-js": "^5.11.0"**

I have installed above versions .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxAoc.png)

I need to get Okta implemented in Angular7